# How to get the MapPin tapped event without callout option?

Tags: iphone

I am using MKMapView where i placed the pin for some address. I need to do like this: If i touch the pin should not show callout and touch event should call. Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method, set the `canShowCallout` property to NO and use `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` to detect the touch:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString *annotIdentifier = @"annot";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pav = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotIdentifier];
    if (!pav)
    {
        pav = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotIdentifier] autorelease];
        pav.canShowCallout = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        pav.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"annotation touched: %@", view.annotation.title);
}
```

Make sure the map view's delegate property is set otherwise these methods won't get called.